# How to change background color to transparent

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-canvas

There is js code of canvas effect
and i want to make the background color transparent and place the video below the text

https://codepen.io/richardwestenra/pen/rZmERo

```
particleSystem.prototype.repaint = function() {
  // clear the screen
  this.ctx.fillStyle = '#1d1d1d';
  this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
};
```

When I try to change the background to transparent, a white background appears below the text.

```
particleSystem.prototype.repaint = function() {
  // clear the screen
  this.ctx.fillStyle = '#1d1d1d00';
  this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
};
```

Comment: You mean [`clearRect`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect)?